# Using jQuery Cookie to keep a div hidden

Tags: jquery

I have a really basic script to close a div, now I want to keep it closed, I understand I can achieve this with jQuery Cookie (which I have uploaded to my site) however this is a tad out of my jQuery coding skills and I have Googled several sites but the examples are all quite complex compared to what I want to achieve is for the user to click the close button once and it will not return with a refresh or revisit for 24 hours.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="files/scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on('click','.close_box',function(){
$(this).parent().fadeTo(300,0,function(){
      $(this).remove();
});
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="warning">Warning message. <div class="close_box">CLOSE</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you need to check if cookie was set on domready and remove `.warning` div. In on click function you need to set cookie. You can also specify options (options goes here) if you want cookie to be removed with browser session or kept for longer time.

```
$(function () {
    if ($.cookie('myCookieName')) {
        $('.warning').remove()
    }
});
$(document).on('click','.close_box',function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeTo(300,0,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $.cookie('myCookieName', '1', {(options goes here)})
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I seam to be getting an error "myCookieName is not defined", the only change to your code is i took out the {(options goes here)} part

Comment: Awesome, that works great, thanks again, one thing I did notice was the warning flashes up for a split second on refresh/page change, any ideas, is it because of the location of the script in the footer rather than the head of the site?

Comment: You can make .warning not visible during load by display:none. and change unload function to this -> $(function () {
    if ($.cookie('myCookieName')) {
        $('.warning').remove()
    } else {
        $('.warning').show()
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs, you can set a cookie when the user closes the box:

`$.cookie('dismissMessages', true, { expires: 1 });`

Then when the user loads the site again, (so, `on document ready`) check for the cookie:

`if( $.cookie('dismissMessages') ){` and hide the box